# Cannot boot past UEFI when installing ubuntu on HP

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, grub-efi

On an HP EliteBook 755 g5 , Ubuntu install fails.

1. Boot into Ubuntu 18.04.1 installation media (which was checksummed by etcher when created).
2. Shows me the Grub boot menu
3. Select **Install Ubuntu** or **Start Ubuntu without installing**
4. Black screen, nothing happens.

I made sure to disable all BIOS boot security, but still nothing happens, so I think something on hp side is stopping it from booting.

Comment: @K7AAY Yeah I thought the same thing, so i made multiple installation drives, and tested it on a separate machine, and it was able to boot into the installer, its just this computer. And I'm using etcher which does verify the drive checksum,

Comment: @K7AAY Nothing, just black, just like every option on the grub menu.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from HP? And firmware for NVMe drive? Not sure about AMD systems otherwise. Is system using AHCI for drives not RAID? If you change be sure to install AHCI drivers into Windows first.

Comment: UEFI is updated from july, and drivers are updated and not using AHCI, I also made sure to disable all security options in bios and disabled legacy and secure boot,

Comment: You need AHCI turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seemed after a ton of research I had to downgrade the firmware of the laptop and add the install args to `nomodeset`

Answer (score 1):

Add these options after `quiet splash`  by pressing "e" at grub screen. It worked for me without downgrade.

`iommu=soft mce=off acpi=strict processor.max_cstate=5 idle=nomwait`

After ubuntu starts make this changes permanent by editing grub file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Following line shouldbe edited:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash iommu=soft mce=off acpi=strict processor.max_cstate=5 idle=nomwait"
```

**Note:*I have reverted /etc/default/grub file after updating kernel 4.20.3 and still working***

Comment: It would be good idea to elaborate on where to add the said options. :)

Comment: @thephoenix01 sure :)